# Does Ruby have a method similar to Emacs align-regexp?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, emacs

Looking for a Ruby method to operate on an array of strings and align them according to a regex given as as an argument.  Emacs has a defun called align-regexp that does this interactively when operating on a region of a buffer.

Here is a portion of the emacs doc string for align-regexp.

For example, let's say you had a list of phone numbers, and wanted to
align them so that the opening parentheses would line up:

```
Fred (123) 456-7890
Alice (123) 456-7890
Mary-Anne (123) 456-7890
Joe (123) 456-7890
```

There is no predefined rule to handle this, but you could easily do it
using a REGEXP like "(".  All you would have to do is to mark the
region, call `align-regexp' and type in that regular expression.
Here is the result:

```
Fred      (123) 456-7890
Alice     (123) 456-7890
Mary-Anne (123) 456-7890
Joe       (123) 456-7890
```

Comment: Ruby is a programming language, and emacs is an editor. Write your Ruby in emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = [
  'Fred (123) 456-7890',
  'Alice (123) 456-7890',
  'Mary-Anne (123) 456-7890',
  'Joe (123) 456-7890',
]
rows = lines.map { |line| line.partition('(') }
pos = rows.map { |row| row[0].size }.max
puts rows.map { |row| row[0] = row[0].ljust(pos); row.join }
```

output:

```
Fred      (123) 456-7890
Alice     (123) 456-7890
Mary-Anne (123) 456-7890
Joe       (123) 456-7890
```

Comment: @sawa, I think this solution is general enough. You can change `(` with any string or regular expression.

Comment: @sawa, The question is mentioning about `(`.

Comment: @sawa, As the name suggest, the [`align-regexp`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands#toc4)  accepts an regular expression.